# Read three lines at a time into an ArrayList java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, bufferedreader

I have the following data in a `.txt` file that I would like to read into an `ArrayList` in Java:

```
GPS BIIR-2  (PRN 13)    
1 24876U 97035A   17141.14457135  .00000003  00000-0  00000-0 0  9998
2 24876  55.5552 228.1750 0035254 106.3776 254.0559  2.00561862145482
GPS BIIR-3  (PRN 11)    
1 25933U 99055A   17141.73713684 -.00000027  00000-0  00000-0 0  9993
2 25933  51.6152  78.7972 0165513  94.1246 263.1302  2.00558460129112
GPS BIIR-4  (PRN 20)    
1 26360U 00025A   17141.81895226  .00000099  00000-0  00000-0 0  9997
2 26360  53.1134 155.9897 0041040  91.6015  67.4278  2.00562427124819
GPS BIIR-5  (PRN 28)    
1 26407U 00040A   17141.94548343 -.00000038  00000-0  00000-0 0  9999
2 26407  56.6412 346.1706 0199324 270.1305 261.3402  2.00566941123498
GPS BIIR-6  (PRN 14)    
1 26605U 00071A   17141.89387574  .00000011  00000-0  00000-0 0  9994
2 26605  55.1263 225.8873 0093188 248.2178 154.4748  2.00565957121094
GPS BIIR-7  (PRN 18)    
1 26690U 01004A   17141.89275187  .00000099  00000-0  00000-0 0  9997
2 26690  53.0355 158.9288 0182848 256.8341 254.6988  2.00552856119496
GPS BIIR-8  (PRN 16)    
1 27663U 03005A   17141.54592882 -.00000038  00000-0  00000-0 0  9991
2 27663  56.7105 345.9236 0092607  24.3398 337.2543  2.00561164104855
GPS BIIR-9  (PRN 21)    
1 27704U 03010A   17141.94336059  .00000017  00000-0  00000-0 0  9995
2 27704  53.8441  99.3104 0242356 264.2597 344.1458  2.00562515103650
GPS BIIR-10 (PRN 22)    
1 28129U 03058A   17141.33287910  .00000097  00000-0  00000-0 0  9991
2 28129  52.9229 158.9448 0077529 260.9570  98.2202  2.00545637 98328
GPS BIIR-11 (PRN 19)    
1 28190U 04009A   17141.74233858 -.00000063  00000-0  00000-0 0  9997
2 28190  55.9902  46.9639 0100903  55.1890 240.6200  2.00564687 96524
GPS BIIR-12 (PRN 23)    
1 28361U 04023A   17141.86069817  .00000018  00000-0  00000-0 0  9997
2 28361  54.1113 221.0276 0118403 219.7092  72.6776  2.00554771 94586
GPS BIIR-13 (PRN 02)    
1 28474U 04045A   17141.27054522  .00000022  00000-0  00000-0 0  9993
2 28474  54.2236  98.7980 0170296 246.9269 339.1728  2.00549707 91965
GPS BIIRM-1 (PRN 17)    
1 28874U 05038A   17141.73783501 -.00000064  00000-0  00000-0 0  9994
2 28874  56.1469  44.2221 0118454 254.4937  59.3377  2.00568905 85376
```

As you can see, the data would be a complete object every three lines. So, how can I add `String` elements to an ArrayList in Java that each consist of three lines in a `.txt` file?

I am successfully reading the entire file into a single element and can search within the string for values, but I would like each set of data (three lines) to be a new element in an `ArrayList`.

Here is the method I am using currently. Obviously this just creates a new element in the ArrayList per line.

```
private void menuLoadTleFileActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setDialogTitle("Choose a TLE file...");
    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
            "TXT Files", "txt");
    chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
    int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File selectedFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        consoleTextArea.append("TLE File Loaded!");
         ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(selectedFile)))
        {
            String currentLine;

            while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(currentLine);
                lines.add(currentLine);

                consoleTextArea.append(currentLine);
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: you have to share your code :)

Comment: Well, calling `readLine()` three times in a row before you loop would be the obvious solution... Please add the code

Comment: If you're using a `BufferedReader` or something, use `BufferedReader.readLine()` 3 times per loop, and store the result in three different variable or in an array. Then, once you've read the 3 lines, add them to the arraylist with concatenation (like l1 + l2 + l3 or something)

Answer (score 0):

An ArrayList can hold a List of arrays.  So, just do something like this:

```
public List<String[]> readGeoMessages(InputStream in) {
    List<String[]> geoMessages=new ArrayList<>();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String str;
    while ((str=reader.readLine())!=null) {
        String[] rec=new String[3];
        rec[0]=str;
        rec[1]=reader.readLine();
        rec[2]=reader.readLine();
        geoMessages.add(rec);
    }
    return geoMessages;
}
```